# Can we share facebook friends leaderboard?

Tags: facebook

I am developing an app which has free and paid version. I'd like to have those 2 apps(free & paid) to use the same leaderboard (facebook), which means using one facebook app id. Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: sad... Thanks for your quick comment though.

Comment: On iOS this should be possible by using URL Scheme Suffixes, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid